# Apache Nifi - Split a large Json file into multiple files with a specified number of records

Tags: apache-nifi

I am a newbie to Nifi and would like some guidance please. 
We want to split a large Json file into multiple files with a specified number of records. I am able to split a file into individual records using SplitJson and the Json Path Expression set as $..* I have also added an UpdateAttribute Processor with filename set to ${filename}_${fragment.index} so that we have the sequence of the files as order is important.
However, we might want to have say a 100,000 records split into 100 files of 1000 records each . What is the easiest way to do this ?
Thanks very much in advance

Comment: MergeContent with `[` header, `]` footer, and `,` delim. So the result will be array of json objects.

Comment: Or mergerecord processor

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `SplitRecord` processor. You can define the number of records to be split per file, such as:

```
Record Reader      CSVReader
Record Writer      CSVRecordSetWriter
Records Per Split  3
```

I have tested with the record,

```
id
1
...
8
```

and it is split into 3 files with the id = (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8).